# 410 a bunch of html pages in IIS

Tags: html, iis, http-status-code-410

I need to do a 410 Gone on a bunch of html pages for a site running on IIS. Is there a simple way to do them all at once, like an htaccess file, or do I have to do it one at a time in IIS?

Answer (score 2):

I do it this way:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( listOf410urls.Contains(Request.RawUrl) )
    {
         Response.StatusCode = 410; Response.End();
    }
}
```

And then I have in webconfig system.webServer

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
    <remove statusCode="410" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="410" path="/Error410.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

This means that all the pages that return 410 will be fetched to the user & search engines using `/Error410.aspx` page.

In Error410.aspx I also set `Response.StatusCode = 410;` otherwise the statuscode will be 200 OK.

Comment: `listOf410urls` being an Array? Brilliant.

Comment: Well done! I had a few thousand pages that needed to 410. fortunately, it was all pages in a specific directory off the root. I was able to do this: HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
if (app.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.IndexOf("/mydirectory") > -1)
{Response.StatusCode = 410; Response.End();}

Comment: one more note... if it was all html pages I need to return as 410, I could have looked for 'html'. That is, as long as ALL html pages are to get a 410 returned.